# Close all other DIVs while one is open - with separate close button

Tags: jquery, toggle, hide, show

I have a bunch of DIVs that can be toggled open and close.
They are opened by clicking on the DIV "case-toggle" and are closed by a separate span called "case-close"
The DIVs that show after clicking have the class "case-popup"
The issue is that multiple DIVs can open at once, but I want only one DIV to be open at once and all others close.
I'm not sure what extra code needs to be added here to achieve that. 
I have searched and searched but nothing I've found has worked while having a separate close button.
Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('.case-toggle').click(
            function(){
             $(this).next('.case-popup').show();  
        }
        );

    $('.case-close').click(
        function(){
         $(this).closest('.case-popup').hide();  
        }
        );

}       
);
```

Your help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line

```
    $('.case-popup').hide();
```

to the `$('.case-toggle').click()` function

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('.case-toggle').click(
      function() {
        $('.case-popup').hide();
        $(this).next('.case-popup').show();
      }
    );

    $('.case-close').click(
      function() {
        $(this).closest('.case-popup').hide();
      }
    );    
  }
);
```

Use it like this

```
   $('.case-toggle').on("click", function() {
        $('.case-popup').hide();
        $(this).next('.case-popup').show();
  });
```

Comment: Would you also happen to know how to change this code so that the click event becomes an 'on click' event, so that this can work within AJAX?